# Can RESTful WCF services be added via "Add Service Reference"?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf, visual-studio-2015

Long time ago, in a world far far away, we used to be able to add web service references to projects simply by right-clicking on the project's References node, and clicking "Add Service Reference". I used to be able to do this with .asmx services, and traditional WCF service.

When I follow different online instructions on "making my WCF RESTful", do I also lose the ability to "Add Service Reference" to those WCF services?  Can WCF based REST services be added this way?

If I use Web API 2, can I "Add Service Reference"?

Assume I'm using the latest of everything - VS2015, etc.

Comment: Duplicate: [Why can't we add a Web API as a “service reference” in Visual Studio the same way we can with WCF or ASMX?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744407/why-cant-we-add-a-web-api-as-a-service-reference-in-visual-studio-the-same-wa)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I follow different online instructions on "making my WCF RESTful", do I also lose the ability to "Add Service Reference" to those WCF services? Can WCF based REST services be added this way?

Kind of.  You can add a REST MEX endpoint, but I don't think you can use that to generate a service proxy.  Though, I think a better question might be, why would you want to?  Web API is the best way to go for REST.

> If I use Web API 2, can I "Add Service Reference"?

No.  Web API doesn't have any type of metadata functionality like WCF.

Comment: Thanks. The more I'm reading, the more it sounds like what you've said - choose to use Web API 2 over WCF when creating new RESTful services. I was just hoping for an easy way to produce a service proxy based on REST services. 

I really like getting using intellisense to know which methods are on a service, and I like generating/getting back strong types that I can use automatically.  I think I'll highly miss these things.

Comment: I wrote a simple generic .NET Web API client that lets you pass whatever types you want into scaffolded Web API controllers.  As such, it only supports GET, POST, PUT, and DELETE, but it solves the problem of having to write new client code for every single Web API controller you write.  For example, `new GenericWebApiClient<Movie>()` will new up a client with Get, GetAll, Update, Delete, and Create methods that all expect or return Movie types.

I'm pretty busy today but I'm on vacation next week.  I'll throw it on GitHub then and get you the link.

Comment: Here you go, use it only for good, never for evil.  :)

https://github.com/CamSoper/CamTheGeek

Comment: @CamSoper — Very nice :-) This is exactly what I've been looking for. I promise to use it only for good.