# I create a WebApi, but cant add it as web reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api

Im following this [**tutorial**](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api). I Create my WebApi and works Ok from the browser. But when try to add it as web reference tell me this error.

> The document at the url http://localhost/WebApi/api/test was not recognized as a known document type.
>   The error message from each known type may help you fix the problem:
>   - Report from 'XML Schema' is 'Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.'.
>   - Report from 'DISCO Document' is 'Data

TestController

```
namespace WebApi.Controllers
{
    public class TestController : ApiController
    {
        public HttpResponseMessage Get()
        {
            return new HttpResponseMessage()
            {
                Content = new StringContent("GET: Test message")
            };
        }

        public HttpResponseMessage Post()
        {
            return new HttpResponseMessage()
            {
                Content = new StringContent("POST: Test message")
            };
        }

        public HttpResponseMessage Put()
        {
            return new HttpResponseMessage()
            {
                Content = new StringContent("PUT: Test message")
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Browser OK, but show error.

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744407/why-cant-we-add-a-web-api-as-a-service-reference-in-visual-studio-the-same-wa

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer in the link. There are many ways you can have access to the WebAPI controllers.

1. You can access from Client side using Javascript,Ajax, AngularJs etc.
2. Any Framework that cam make Http request for example if u want to install     ASP.Net WebAPI Client on any .Net App. (Console, WindowsForm etc.) then add the reference before you instantiate HttpClient().
   See sample code below

   ```
       var client =new HttpClient(); 
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml")); 
   var result = client.GetAsync(new Uri("http://localhost:16665/api/myApiControllerName")).Result;
   ```